# phpMyAdmin database export file size changes with each tentative

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export, cpanel

I have a MediaWiki wiki hosted by a provider. I do not have terminal access. I am trying to download (read: export) the MySQL database with phpMyAdmin. The database total size is, according to the web-hosting cPanel, 932.94 MB. phpMyAdmin puts the total size of the 51 tables at 732.8 MiB.

My problem is that I do not seem to be able to download the entire database (all 51 tables at once) because of the size (?). Therefore, I resorted to downloading the table XXX_text alone (as its size is 386.6 MiB and is by far the biggest db), and the rest together. However, each time I download the XXX_text table, I get a different size. I am expecting something between 350 and 400 MB, but so far I got the following sizes (examples, uncompressed): 54.8 MB, 87.9 MB, 101.5 MB, 74.7 MB, 44 MB, 79.6 MB, 58 MB...

You get the picture. There is no consistency and so far I haven't found a pattern. I know the wiki is not accessed by anyone as it has been suspended (no one can reach it, not even me).

Both export methods (Quick and Custom) lead to the same export size inconsistency issue.

However, when I download a small table (e.g., XXX_archive which phpMyAdmin size lists at 464 KiB), I get a consistent 347 KB, repeated, XXX_archive.sql file.

Any ideas how to get the (preferably entire) database? Are there any settings I should do in phpMyadmin? Quid?

**phpMyAdmin technical details**

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Server type: Percona Server
- Server version: 5.6.32-78.1 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 78.1, Revision 8bb53b6
- Protocol version: 10
- Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
- phpMyAdmin version: 4.3.8 (not upgradable)

**Hosting technical details**

- cPanel: 62.0 (build 46)
- Apache: 2.2.34
- PHP: 5.4.24
- MySQL: 5.6.32-78.1
- Perl: 5.24.1
- Hosting type: Shared IP

**Mediawiki technical details**

- MediaWiki version: 1.29.2

Answer (score 0):

In cPanel, should be able to download a copy of your database by simply logging into cPanel and go to the ‘Backup’ section. (cPanel >> Home >> Files >> Backup).

Then click on the link for your database name. It will prompt your to download your database in a compressed archive (tar.gz) to your local computer.

Comment: Found the following: cPanel >> Site Backup Pro. Here I can either Browse or Download MySQL databases and tables.
If I Browse, I get a list of all the MySQL databases I have. I can check from one to all of them. If I check the one I want and the click on "download tar" (or "download zip" I get a "Click Here if your download does not start automatically". After several minutes, as nothing happens, I click on "Click Here" and I am redirected to a white page saying "invalid key:" and nothing happens (I tried waiting more than 30 minutes, everything leads to the same "invalid key:").

Comment: The host installed a brand new cPanel. Home does not provide any backup options, unlike suggested by Antti A. Apparently, the only way to back the MySQL databases up is through phpMyAdmin. More than 2 years after my initial post, the problem remains the same: when downloaded the biggest table (XXX_text) is almost never twice the same size and all the gunzipped files are corrupt when imported in my local phpMyAdmin (MAMP installation), whereas the other databases have been successfully exporte then imported locally.

Any ideas?